# Launching C applications on an AMI's startup in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Does anyone know if it's possible to make my own AMI's for use in the AWS Elastic Beanstalk? The AMI would simply have a C program that executes when the instance starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Simply spin an EC2 instance up based on their stock beanstalk AMIs, which I believe Amazon makes available in the community AMI list, make your changes, cut an AMI off that fixed instance, and use that newest AMI id in your beanstalk application's configuration.

There is nothing abnormal or unusual about this.

Alternatively, you can use UserData and [CloudInit](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit) to download and launch the application on instantiation. This would avoid having to change the stock AMI.